# Active Directory Changing Password C# code PrincipleContext causes ComException

Tags: .net, active-directory

I'm working on a simple program that will allow a user to enter their username, old password and new password to update their Active Directory account. There are plenty of code examples on Stack Overflow however, every time I try

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName)
```

I receive a ComException.

Comment: What's the error code of the COMException? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception.errorcode.aspx)

Comment: ConnectedServer 'context.ConnectedServer' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' string {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}

Comment: Check for an inner exception as well. The error code should look like `0x800A03EC`. Once you have that error code, you'll be able to search on that.

Comment: Looks like the error code is -2147016694 which seems to be an issue with an update to AD. Will check today to see if we need to apply a fix to AD.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work once I passed in the domain name and additional properties to the PrincipalContext object.

```
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, "OU=OrganizationName,OU=Users,OU=!OrgSiteName,DC=OrgSite,DC=com")
```